# In Internet Explorer I can't write to an input element after click on it - weird bug

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have a very very weird bug. In Google Chrome everything is OK, only IE has this problem.

I use an AngularJS and ui-select component to create a multiple selects.

In IE, when I click into text input element, I can't type anything and even placeholder is not removed.

[image]

But when I click to URL address bar or click somewhere into DOM in Developer Tools (after hitting F12) first and then I click into that input, it normally works and I can write into input to filter options.

[image]

I tried a lot of with focus/blur, but nothing helps me. Please, did someone have similar problem?

Code:
[image]

Turns to:
[image]

Comment: can u provide some code probably a plunker

Comment: without your code nothing can be done. update your post